# Show that Kernel density estimate integrates to 1

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions, improper-integrals

I'm trying to show that the Kernel density estimate

$$ f(x) = \frac1{nb}\sum_{i=1}^nK \left(\frac {X_i - x}b\right) $$

actually integrates to 1. The $X_i$ are iid and K is a symmetric probability density function; in particular, K integrates to 1. What I get is

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac1{nb}\sum_{i=1}^nK\left(\frac {X_i - x}b\right) dx$$
$$ = \frac1{nb}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^nK\left(\frac {X_i - x}b\right) dx $$

$$=\frac1{nb}\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K\left(\frac {X_i - x}b\right) dx$$
$$=\frac1{b}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K\left(\frac {X_i - x}b\right) dx$$

Using as a substitution

$$ u = \frac {X_i - x}b$$
$$ dx = -b du$$

we get

$$=\frac1{b}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K(u) (-b) du $$
$$= (-b) \frac1{b}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K(u) du  = -1$$

Something must have gone wrong with the integration. I know that $f(x)$ is often defined differently, as

$$ f'(x) = \frac1{nb}\sum_{i=1}^nK\left(\frac {x - X_i}b\right) $$

and with this version I can show that it integrates to 1. However $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$ should be equivalent as $K$ is symmetric. So there is some flaw in my calculations (my knowledge about integration with substitution is purely heuristic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)~{\rm d}x &= \frac{1}{nb}\sum_{i = 1}^n \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} K\left(\frac{X_i - x}{b}\right){\rm d}x &  \text{with } ~u = \frac{X_i - x}{b},~{\rm d}u = -{\rm d}x/b \\
&= -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} K(u)~{\rm du} \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \cancelto{1}{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}K(u){\rm d}u} \\
&= \frac{1}{\cancel{n}} \cancel{n} = 1
\end{align}

The part you need to pay attention to is the limits, when $x\to +\infty$ you have $u \to -\infty$ and *vice versa*. So the limits of the integral change of order

Comment: How do You know that You can use substitution? I mean does density function (here K) has to have an antiderivative - because that's one of the assumptions for substitution.

Comment: @strefa61 This statement is part of the question "... $K$ is a symmetric probability density function..", which means is an integrable/normalizable function

Comment: I know these are basic questions but I really can't get it.
1. Does symmetricity influences the intregability and have antiderivative?
2. I can't see in the deffinition of density anything about have antiderivative (It has to be integrable, yes, but it doesn't mean we can use substitution for it).

Comment: great answer! I cant believe someone asked this question and someone answered! very useful! thank you!