# Probability vs Likelihood of a Single Point?

Tags: probability

**I am trying to understand if the concept of "probability density" can be (easily) explained in English.**

To illustrate my problem, I have simulated a dataset containing the heights of 100 students (in R):

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 100 
mu1 <- 160 
mu2 <- 180 
sd1 <- 5 
sd2 <- 6 
p <- 0.8 

heights <- c(rnorm(n*p, mean = mu1, sd = sd1), rnorm(n*(1-p), mean = mu2, sd = sd2))
```

Then, I made two plots using this data:

```
library(ggplot2)

heights_df <- data.frame(heights)

heights_density <- density(heights)
h <- heights_density$bw
kernel <- "Gaussian" 

binwidth <- 2

p1 <- ggplot(heights_df, aes(x = heights)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = binwidth, color = "black", fill = "white") +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(x = "Height (cm)", y = "Count", title = "Plot 1: Simulated Student Heights") +
    annotate("text", x = 170, y = 20, label = paste0("Binwidth: ", binwidth))



p2 = ggplot(heights_df, aes(x = heights)) +
    geom_density() +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(x = "Height (cm)", y = "Density", title = "Simulated Student Heights") +
    annotate("text", x = 170, y = 0.04, label = paste0("Bandwidth: ", round(h, 2), "\nKernel: ", kernel)) + ggtitle("Plot 2: Simulated Student Heights")
```

[image]

- The first graph (i.e. p1) is very easy to interpret - this graph shows that the number of students between each height range.
- The second graph (i.e. p2) is a bit more complicated.

As I understand, the "smooth line" that we are seeing being fit is a Kernel Density Estimate (KDE). If I understand correctly, a Kernel Density Estimate can be seen as an approximation to a Probability Distribution Function (i.e. a Kernel Density Function can be integrated between ranges to find out the probability - [Show that Kernel density estimate integrates to 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067653/show-that-kernel-density-estimate-integrates-to-1)). Here is a generic KDE formula along with the KDE based on the Gaussian Kernel (the one being used in the above graph) - this can be used to estimate the Density at any given point:

- Generic KDE: $$
  \hat{f}_h(x) = \frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i=1}^{n} K\left(\frac{x-x_i}{h}\right)$$
- Gaussian KDE : $$
  \hat{f}_h(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{h\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-x_i}{h}\right)^2\right)$$

**My Question:** I am still looking for an intuitive way to explain the idea of densities in English.

- For example, Plot 2 shows that 160 cm has a corresponding density value of 0.06 : of course, this DOES NOT MEAN that 6% of all students have a height of 160 cm.
- On the other hand, we know that probability of observing a specific height is 0 - this is by definition. We can only observe "ranges of heights" and associate a probability to a given range.

The best thing I can come up with at the moment is to say that the Kernel Density Estimate can be numerically integrated to estimate the probability of observing heights between a certain range.

But beyond this, I do not know how to explain the concept of a single density - for example, **I don't think it is correct to say that a height of 160 cm is expected to be "denser" that a height of 170 cm.**

But as such, can this be tied to the concept of Likelihoods? Afterall, a (continuous) Probability Function evaluated at a specific point is said to be the density as well as the likelihood at that given point. **Thus, could we say that, if 160 cm has an estimated density of 0.06 and 170 cm has an estimate density of 0.01 - could we make some statement similar to "we are 6 times more likely to observe a student with 160 cm versus a student with 170 cm"?**

**Is there some straightforward way to interpret and explain the meaning of a single (individual) density? Or are individual densities meaningless by definition and they should be only analyzed through ranges ?**

Thanks!

Comment: $f_X(x):=\frac{d}{dx}\left(F_X(x)\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a more correct way (but not "fully rigorous") to say it is that it is 6 times more likely to observe a height *around* 160cm than *around* 170cm, where "around" represents a very small quantity compared to the range of values you are considering (eg. 1cm). That is, $P(X \in [a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon]) = 2\epsilon f(a) +o(\epsilon)$, using Landau notation : the linear approximation $P(X \in [a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon]) = 2\epsilon f(a) $ makes sense for small $\epsilon$.

You are correct, it does not make much sense looking at the probability density pointwise. This is because probablity density is a quantity that is "made" to be integrated, as it is itself a spatial derivative (that of the cumulative distribution function). Think of it like the density of a material : we often care about the *mass* of an object or system, but this leads us to the study of its density (which is the spatial derivative of the mass!)